# How to access dictionary values when you can't input the key?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

So I'm trying to go through a book used to teach different types of models and algorithms and I came upon this issue. My code is below. Essentially it generates a text output of a graph. Individual points are referred to as "vertices" and the lines connecting them are "edges". What I'm currently trying to do is check if an edge exists between two vertices.

```
class Graph(dict):
    def __init__(self, vs=[], es=[]):
        for v in vs:
            self.add_vertex(v)
        for e in es:
            self.add_edge(e)

    def add_vertex(self, v):
        self[v] = {}

    def add_edge(self, e):
        v,w = e
        self[v][w] = e
        self[w][v] = e

    def get_edge(self, v, w):
        g = dict(self)
        keys = g.keys()
        return type(keys[0])

    def remove_edge(self, e):
        pass

    def vertices(self):
        keys = self.keys()
        return keys

class Vertex(object):
    def __init__(self, label=''):
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Vertex(%s)' % repr(self.label)

    __str__ = __repr__

class Edge(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, e1, e2):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (e1, e2))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Edge(%s, %s)' % (repr(self[0]), repr(self[1]))

    __str__ = __repr__

v = Vertex('v')
w = Vertex('w')
e = Edge(v, w)
print e

g = Graph([v,w],[e])
print g


edge = Graph.get_edge(g, 'v', 'w')
print edge
```

The issue is here:

```
def get_edge(self, v, w):
        g = dict(self)
        keys = g.keys()
        return type(keys[0])
```

I cannot access the values in the dictionary because I can't use the keys, the return type line shows why:

Output:

```
Edge(Vertex('v'), Vertex('w'))
{Vertex('v'): {Vertex('w'): Edge(Vertex('v'), Vertex('w'))}, Vertex('w'):{Vertex('v'): Edge(Vertex('v'), Vertex('w'))}}
<class '__main__.Vertex'>
```

The issue is the keys aren't strings, integers, or really anything I can reference, they're generated from calling the Vertex class. Is there some way I could reference the keys that I'm missing? My goal is to have the method return the Edge requested if it exists.

Comment: "I cannot access the values in the dictionary because I can't use the keys" - what do you mean, you can't use the keys? They're right there, `v` and `w`. Why would instances of Vertex not be "really anything I can reference"?

Comment: You didn't implement `__eq__`, `__ne__`, and `__hash__`, so your vertices and edges are all compared by identity. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Agree with user above. You  need to either implement a way to uniquely hash each vertex, or implement a strictly explicit way to determine if two vertices are the same. Otherwise, python will check if they are the same _instance_ not necessarily the same _node_, however you choose to define a node.